# MySql: extracting distinct entries from three different columns of same table

Tags: mysql, join, distinct

I have a table called `deals` which stores `client_id1`, `client_id2`, `client_id3`.

These ids correspond to `clients` table which have `clientName` and `client_id` fields.

How can I create a string array of names whose ids are there in any of the three columns of table deals.

Comment: You should probably consider normalizing your data though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Client) FROM (
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id1 = clients.client_id
UNION ALL
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id2 = clients.client_id
UNION ALL
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id3 = clients.client_id)
GROUP BY Client
```

### Explanation:

#### Get client from one table:

```
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id1 = clients.client_id
```

#### The union will get them from the other tables, too

```
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id1 = clients.client_id
UNION ALL
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id2 = clients.client_id
UNION ALL
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id3 = clients.client_id)
```

#### Now to get a Comma-Seperated-String, either do this clientside (php) or let the MySQL server do it, using a [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Client) FROM (
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id1 = clients.client_id
UNION ALL
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id2 = clients.client_id
UNION ALL
 SELECT clientName as Client 
 FROM deals JOIN clients
 ON deals.client_id3 = clients.client_id)
GROUP BY Client
```